# Tor/Python scraping: timeout or 'tuple index out of range' - fix?

Tags: python, tor

I'm trying to scrape a website.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socks
import socket

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', 9150, True)
s = socks.socksocket()
s.settimeout(None)

s.connect(('www.bangalore-property-buy.com', 80))
s.sendall('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n')
s.sendall('Host: www.bangalore-property-buy.com\r\n')
print(s.recv(1024))


in> python telnet.py
HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
</body></html>
```

How do i fix this? I get the above error when I use the Tor browser. If i start tor manually like so: tor -f /etc/tor/torrc then i get:

```
python telnet.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telnet.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.connect(('104.219.248.96', 80))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 369, in connect
    self.__negotiatesocks5(destpair[0],destpair[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 236, in __negotiatesocks5
    raise Socks5Error(ord(resp[1]),_generalerrors[ord(resp[1])])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: if the tuple is empty, then you get IndexError. Be sure its not empty.

Comment: If you don't want people to link to you through SO posts, then anonymize your code.  use example.com rather than your website name.